# How to pull multi scatterplot of all explanatory variables to response variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

How to pull multi scatterplot of all explanatory variables to response variables in python. the error generated as below, No matter I set squeeze as True or False. 
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 4, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=False, squeeze=False)

for i,col in enumerate(chef_num.columns[1:]):

    sns.scatterplot(x=chef_num[col], y=chef_num['REVENUE'], ax=ax[i])
```

Comment: What is `ax`? The error is due to `ax[i]`. I assume it is an axis, therefore it is as the error says, it cannot be subscriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of Axes is called `axes`, not `ax.` You should call `sns.scatterplot(..., ax=axes[i,j])`

Note that `axes` is a 2D array, you therefore need two counters, or iterate over a flattened array of axes:

```
for ax,col in zip(axes.flat, chef_num.columns[1:]):
    sns.scatterplot(x=chef_num[col], y=chef_num['REVENUE'], ax=ax)
```